# Get text next to selected element in lxml / Python

Tags: python, html, lxml, elementtree

I have the following HTML markup and I'd like to get the English description as plain text out of this snippet - without the "English, and without any tags":

```
from lxml import etree


html = '''
    <td class="description">
    <p><b>English:</b> Ulm, Germany, old town with Münster, city wall and Metzgerturm, as seen from the south bank of the river Danube.</p>
    <p><b>Deutsch:</b> Ulm, Ansicht der Altstadt vom rechten Donauufer aus. Abgebildet ist das Donauschwabenufer, von der Altstadt sind erkennbar: Das dominante Münster mit Hauptturm, Schiff und zwei Chortürmen; unterhalb des Hauptturms des Münsters zwei Giebel, die zur historischen Krone gehören (linker Giebel größtenteils von Bäumen verdeckt); die Spitze der neuen, gläsernen Stadtbibliothek von Gottfried Böhm; weiter rechts zwei Giebel des Rathauses (gelb-braun); am rechten Rand der Metzgerturm als Teil der Stadtbefestigung.</p>
    </td>
'''

tree = etree.fromstring(html)
for el in tree.xpath('//td[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " description ")]/div|p'):
    print etree.tostring(el)
```

With this script I get the single paragraphs including all tags, but I'm stuck there ... The paragraphs may be DIVs, as well; therefore I've used div|p inside the xpath.

The lxml solution should also work with DIV containers like this:

```
<td class="description">
    <div class="description mw-content-ltr et" dir="ltr" lang="et" style=""><span class="language et" title=""><b>Eesti:</b></span> Olen loonud selle pildi, kui ma nägin arutelu uue Wiki logo.</div>
    <div class="description mw-content-ltr en" dir="ltr" lang="en" style=""><span class="language en" title=""><b>English:</b></span> "Prototype" for new Wiktionary Logo</div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text  you want to get is tail of `b` tags:

```
import lxml.html

html = u'''
    <td class="description">
    <p><b>English:</b> Ulm, Germany, old town with Münster, city wall and Metzgerturm, as seen from the south bank of the river Danube.</p>
    <p><b>Deutsch:</b> Ulm, Ansicht der Altstadt vom rechten Donauufer aus. Abgebildet ist das Donauschwabenufer, von der Altstadt sind erkennbar: Das dominante Münster mit Hauptturm, Schiff und zwei Chortürmen; unterhalb des Hauptturms des Münsters zwei Giebel, die zur historischen Krone gehören (linker Giebel größtenteils von Bäumen verdeckt); die Spitze der neuen, gläsernen Stadtbibliothek von Gottfried Böhm; weiter rechts zwei Giebel des Rathauses (gelb-braun); am rechten Rand der Metzgerturm als Teil der Stadtbefestigung.</p>
    </td>
    <td class="description">
        <div class="description mw-content-ltr et" dir="ltr" lang="et" style=""><span class="language et" title=""><b>Eesti:</b></span> Olen loonud selle pildi, kui ma nägin arutelu uue Wiki logo.</div>
        <div class="description mw-content-ltr en" dir="ltr" lang="en" style=""><span class="language en" title=""><b>English:</b></span> "Prototype" for new Wiktionary Logo</div>
    </td>
'''

tree = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
for el in tree.cssselect('td.description p b, td.description span'):
    if el.text_content().startswith('English'):
        print(el.tail.strip())
```

output:

```
Ulm, Germany, old town with Münster, city wall and Metzgerturm, as seen from the south bank of the river Danube.
"Prototype" for new Wiktionary Logo
```

**NOTE** You need to use `lxml.html`. Otherwise, you can't use `text_content()` method.

Comment: @SimonSteinberger, Could you update the question with the html that contains `div`?

Comment: Done - I'd like to extract only the English description.

Comment: Ok, but I still get the non-English descriptions, too. I'm trying to extract only these two sentences: "Ulm, Germany ..." and "Prototype for ..."

Comment: @SimonSteinberger, I updated the answer again; which use `if` statement.